# How to acces an external link without opening it, just loading it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, url

Maybe is a strange title but all I want is to do so:

I have an `arduino webserver` and an `webserver`

My `arduino server` can receive data via `url` like

`192.168.1.2?light=1` - light on

`192.168.1.2?light=0` - light off

It is working just fine, but the problem is when I put that link anywhere on an website (in button or just normal links) the `arduino server` is opening in browser, is there possible to just load it using `ajax`, `js` or `jquery` or just simply using `html`?

Comment: Have you tried `curl` ?

Comment: `curl` is an overkill in this situation. All you really need is and AJAX call attached to a click event on the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a webpage with jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<a class="access-only" href="http://192.168.1.2?light=1">Turn on the light</a>
<a class="access-only" href="http://192.168.1.2?light=0">Turn off the light</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach click handler to all "access-only" links.
    $('a.access-only').click(function() {
        // Once the link is clicked, access its URL with a GET request.
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
            // Do nothing here, the URL has been accessed.
        });

        // Return false to prevent the browser's default click action.
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, i choose your answer because is the most complete, thanks for others too, it is just working fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

If want to use this link from a webpage then (requires jQuery):

```
$.get('http://192.168.1.2?light=1', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(".yourAtag").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url: this.href, success: function(result){
        alert('success!');
    }});
});
```